# Logout function not working anymore

Tags: php, session, logout

I have a few problems with my website to solve, but first of all is logout function for user.

```
   /* FUNCTION: Logout set */
function logout()
{
    $appid  = $this->db->get_where('general_settings', array(
        'type' => 'fb_appid'
    ))->row()->value;
    $secret = $this->db->get_where('general_settings', array(
        'type' => 'fb_secret'
    ))->row()->value;
    $config = array(
        'appId' => $appid,
        'secret' => $secret
    );
    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/home/logged_out', 'refresh');
}

/* FUNCTION: Logout */
function logged_out()
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'successful_signout');
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/home/', 'refresh');
}
```

it redirects to index.php/home/logout and doesn't give a redirect to index.php/home as it should, it just stays a blank page at logout

Answer (score 0):

Just had to delete facebook api for login and that's it.. simple solution always works >:|